# Return Clean PartialView in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

,Hi all,

When ı start my project , project opens in menu partial view.

Menu has Customer and Report

İf ı click to customer , customer page opens.Then if ı click to Report page , Report pages appears with Customer Page.

I need to clean CustomerPartial if ı click to report in menu.

I am using json,

My Report ActionResult

```
public ActionResult ReportSearchPartial(MyModel model)
{
var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("_ReportPartialView", model);
return Json(stringView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the best way for your menu approach would be rendering a Menu.cshtml partial View in a section in each View, that contains a menu for the desired object (Customer or Report).

Think about a folder structure like this:

- Views

  - Customer

    - Menu.cshtml
    - Index.cshtml

In each customer view e.g. "Index" you can render your Menu Partial within a section like this:

```
@section Menu {
    @Html.Partial("Menu", ViewData)
}
<h1>Customer</h1>
```

If you have a lot of customer views, create a customer layout view that renders the menu section for customer. I won't use Json where its not needed. The Menu view could contain an Ajax search form if you want. Hope I got you right.